# How to compare arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

I need to print the largest numbers in an array but my program keeps outputting the wrong numbers. What am i doing wrong?

```
int main(void) 
{
    int i, x,largest1,largest2, nums[5][4] = { { 5, 6, 8, 9 }, { 3, -55, 6, 89 }, { 1023, 43, -2, 0 }, { 0, 12, 45, 12 }, { -4, 901, 34, 294 } };
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            largest1 = 0;
            largest2 = 0;
            if (nums[i] > largest1)
                largest1 = nums[i];
            if (nums[x] > largest2)
                largest2 = nums[x];
        }
    }
    printf("\n 1st largest: %d \n 2nd largest: %d \n\n", largest1, largest2);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: sort each array first and compare the last element of two arrays to find largest element.

Comment: @Khemar Bryan You marked a bad answer as the best answer. If you want I will show how the program should be written correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please check the data type of `nums[i]`, its not an `int.` What you need is compare each value, say `nums[i][x]`
2. Do not initialize your largest number holder inside the loop. Otherwise, the largest number from previous iteration will be lost.
3. if the array contains *all* `-ve` numbers, initializing the highest number holder will `0` is faulty.

Check the below code<sup>[[ Tested on linux ]]</sup> for getting the idea.  [For largest number only]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)  {

        int i, x,largest1, nums[5][4] = { { 5, 6, 8, 9 }, { 3, -55, 6, 89 }, { 1023, 43, -2, 0 }, { 0, 12, 45, 12 }, { -4, 901, 34, 294 } };
        largest1 = INT_MIN;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
                for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                {

                        if (nums[i][x] > largest1)
                                largest1 = nums[i][x];
                }
        }
        printf("Largest number is %d\n", largest1);

        return 0;

}
```

---

EDIT:

The code modification to include the second largest [and so on..] number display, is as per below logic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)  {

        int i, x,largest1,largest2, nums[5][4] = { { 5, 6, 8, 9 }, { 3, -55, 6, 89 }, { 1023, 43, -2, 0 }, { 0, 12, 45, 12 }, { -4, 901, 34, 294 } };
        largest1 = INT_MIN;
        largest2 = INT_MIN;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
                for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                {

                        if (nums[i][x] > largest2)
                                largest2 = nums[i][x];
                        if ( largest2 > largest1)
                        {
                                largest2 = largest1;
                                largest1 = nums[i][x];
                        }
                }
        }
        printf("Largest number is %d, second largest is %d\n", largest1, largest2);

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: still above program is not giving him second largest array

Comment: @KhemarBryan if this (or any other) answer has helped you to solve your problem, please accept the answer by clicking on `accept`[tick] on upper left hand side of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should initialized largest1 and largest2 variables with the smallest possible integer values. Initializing them with 0 will give wrong result if all the numbers in your array are negative integers.

Also you should not re-initialize the largest1 and largest2 everytime you enter the inner loop.

I've corrected your code below. Please note that I've not tested the following code myself.

```
int i, x;
int largest1 = -32766;
int largest2 = -32767;
int nums[5][4] = { { 5, 6, 8, 9 }, { 3, -55, 6, 89 }, { 1023, 43, -2, 0 }, { 0, 12, 45, 12 }, { -4, 901, 34, 294 } };

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        if (nums[i][x] > largest1) {
            largest2 = largest1;
            largest1 = nums[i][x];
        } else if (num[i][x] > largest2) {
            largest2 = num[i][x];
        }
    }
}

printf("\n 1st largest: %d \n 2nd largest: %d \n\n", largest1, largest2);
system("pause");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int main(void) 
{
    int i, x,largest1,largest2, nums[5][4] = { { 5, 6, 8, 9 }, { 3, -55, 6, 89 }, { 1023, 43, -2, 0 }, { 0, 12, 45, 12 }, { -4, 901, 34, 294 } };
    largest1 = 0;
    largest2 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            if (nums[i][x] > largest1)
                largest1 = nums[i][x];
            if (nums[i][x] > largest2 && nums[i][x] < largest1)
                largest2 = nums[i][x];
        }
    }
    printf("\n 1st largest: %d \n 2nd largest: %d \n\n", largest1, largest2);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: how is the above program going to print second largest no.? o.o

Comment: just add `if (nums[i][x] > largest2 && nums[i][x]<largest1)`

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following modifications. You have to access a 2-D array with 2 parameters to get that [x,y] value to compare.

```
int main(void)  {

int i, x,largest1,largest2, nums[5][4] = { { 5, 6, 8, 9 }, { 3, -55, 6, 89 }, { 1023, 43, -2, 0 }, { 0, 12, 45, 12 }, { -4, 901, 34, 294 } };
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        largest1 = 0;
        largest2 = 0;
        if (nums[i][x] > largest1)
            largest1 = nums[i][x];
        if (nums[i][x] > largest2)
            largest2 = nums[i][x];
    }
}
printf("\n 1st largest: %d \n 2nd largest: %d \n\n", largest1, largest2);
system("pause");
}
```

Hope it helps!
Please mark the answer right if its helpful and close the question.

Comment: please explain `printf("\n 1st largest: %d \n 2nd largest: %d \n\n", largest1, largest2);`

Answer (score 0):

You can move all the integer to a one dimensional array... then sort it. Then print the largest two element. Try this code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {

int i, x,largest1,largest2, save[30], j=0, nums[5][4] = { { 5, 6, 8, 9 }, { 3, -55, 6, 89 }, {   1023, 43, -2, 0 }, { 0, 12, 45, 12 }, { -4, 901, 34, 294 } };
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        save[j++]=nums[i][x];
    }
}
sort(save,save+j);
printf("\n 1st largest: %d \n 2nd largest: %d \n\n", save[j-1], save[j-2]);
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

everyone has already provided you with syntactically correct program.

just a slight addition (I thought may be this is what u wanted according to your prog) :

```
  if (nums[i][x] > largest1)
{
largest2 = largest1;
          largest1 = nums[i][x];
}

if (nums[i][x] > largest2)
          largest2 = nums[i][x];
```

then largest1 and largest2 will have ur desired values.
and yeah, don't forget to initialize your initial values to lowest limit of int first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.
Here we are assigning new max value to `largest1` and if we are getting again new max value we will assign old max value to `largest2` , which will become the second largest value.

```
int main(void) 
{
    int i, x,largest1,largest2, nums[5][4] = { { 5, 6, 8, 9 }, { 3, -55, 6, 89 }, { 1023, 43, -2, 0 }, { 0, 12, 45, 12 }, { -4, 901, 34, 294 } };
    largest1 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {

        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            largest1 = 0;
            largest2 = 0;
            if (nums[i][x] > largest1){
                largest2 = largets1;   // assign last max value to `largest2`, it will be second max
                largest1 = nums[i][x]; // getting new max value
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n 1st largest: %d \n 2nd largest: %d \n\n", largest1, largest2);
    system("pause");
}
```